# If X ≤p Y can Y ≤p X?

Tags: algorithm, polynomials

I think the answer is no, but I'm having trouble with how I understand the problem.
In layman, it's essentially asking that if problem x can be reduced to problem y in polynomial time then y can also be reduced to x in polynomial time, right?
And from how it's written using inequalities, it should be false.

If X ≤p Y in layman this suggests that X can be reduced in polynomial time to Y

The question is then can Y ≤p X which in layman suggests that y be reduced in polynomial time to X

This problem is just confusing me a little.

Comment: This question might be better suited to the [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) SE site.

Comment: @3ocene better [cs.se], as this isn't research-level.

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware of either of those sites!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean to ask "Does X ≤p Y imply that Y ≤p X ?".

The answer is no.  For example 2-SAT can be reduced to 3-SAT easily, but 3-SAT can't be reduced to 2-SAT in P-time unless P=NP.

If P=NP the answer is still no.  For example, any P-time decision problem can be reduced to a halting problem, but the halting problem is undecidable.

Answer (score 0):

#### The answer:

So we have `X ≤p Y`. You are asking, is it possible that also `Y ≤p X`?

Well consider this: What if `X` and `Y` are the same problem? Then, trivially, `X` can be reduced to itself in polynomial time (by just passing through the original problem instance), so we have `X ≤p Y`. But then it follows by the same argument that `Y ≤p X`!

Thus we have found an example such that `X ≤p Y` and `Y ≤p X` so the answer to your question is yes.

(However, it is of course **not** true that ANY problems `X` and `Y` can be reduced in both ways in polynomial time.)

#### Analogy to integers:

As you seem to be pointing out in your question as well, there are definitely some similarities between `≤p` and normal inequality `≤` between e.g. integers: Say `a ≤ b`. Can it then be true that `b ≤ a`? Well yes! Whenever `a = b`.

In the context of computational problems, two problems `X` and `Y` do not have to be identical for them to be reducible in both directions however. (It is always easy to find two problems which are identical but for some arbitrary detail.)

For instance (on a somewhat higher level), the problem of finding the **largest** value in an array of integers can be easily reduced to the problem of finding the **smallest** (by simply negating all the elements). Then trivially, we can also reduce the problem of finding the **smallest** integer to that of finding the **largest** (by simply negating again).

Comment: `Thus we have found an example such that X ≤p Y and Y ≤p X so the answer to your question is yes` - you can't make a judgement based on a single true fact, you probably confused it with "counterexample" i.e. a single false fact disproves a proposition

Comment: `if X ≤p Y, can Y ≤p X?` I can't see what this means apart from "is it possible to find two problems `X` and `Y` so that they can be reduced to each other in polynomial time?" Well in this case, finding one such example does indeed prove that it can. (Just in case OP was in fact asking whether this holds for EVERY two problems where `X ≤p Y`, I added a parenthesis saying no.)